# Why VSCode does not recognize my ReasonML code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, reason

I wrote ReasonML code on VSCode, but VSCode does not recognize it.

-I installed VSCode.
-I installed reason-vscode by Jared Forsyth.

What else may I install to make it work?

Note: This is my first time using VSCode so it is possible that there are not necessary installations.

Any suggestion will help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed [BuckleScript](https://bucklescript.github.io/)? Maybe it's what you are missing.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you said, plus I changed my file's extention to '.re' instead of '.txt' and finally now the code is recognized and colored. I'm new to the environment and ReasonML so your comment helped me so much, really appreciate it:)